# How to subscribe on Activated event in a Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

Do anyone know, how to subscribe on Activated event in a Windows Phone 8.1 Universal App?

In Windows Phone 8, I have used:

```
PhoneApplicationService.Current.Activated +=
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WP8.1 Runtime has little different lifecycle - [see MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh464925.aspx). Depending on your needs you can use:

- [App.Current.Resuming event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.application.resuming.aspx) is called when you resume  your app after it had been suspended by the OS - very often, typically few seconds after you navigate away, see also [How to Resume an app](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh465110.aspx),
- [Windows.Current.Activated](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/windows.ui.xaml.window.activated) is called when *Window* is activated/deactivated - you will have to check event's args. This event doesn't mean that your app had been suspended. You should also look out because this event will be fired for example when you show a dialog (when your window loses focus).
- override methods from [Application class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/windows.ui.xaml.application) - after using file pickers, sharing a target and more.

Answer (score 0):

In windows phone 8.1 universal app use following code to subscribe for activated event.

```
 Window.Current.Activated += Current_Activated;
```

Hope this helps!